# Gradebook Simulation

Tags: processing

I am trying to simulate a student in a grade book where it needs to return the students name, grade level, and classes. I know how to declare the name, grade levels, and classes but I do not know how to get them to return and print to the console.

This code is through the newest version of Processing.

```java
void draw ()
{
    print();
}

//creating class
class Student
{
    String name;
    int grade;
    String[] classes;

    Student(String nameInput, int gradeInput, String[] classesInput)
    {
        int grade=gradeInput;
        String name=nameInput;
        String[] classesInput;
    }

    String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    int getGrade()
    {
        return this.grade;
    }
}

void printClasses()
{
    println("Biology,Math,English,History,Spanish");
}
```

the code is expected to print the student's name, grade level, and classes to the console but with the code I have, nothing happens.

Comment: Your code doesn't attempt to create any instances of the `Student` class, so it isn't clear why you expect anything to happen.

Comment: I'm guessing maybe you have more code than what you've shown? You never instantiate any `Student` objects, and you have no such `print()` method defined. As written, it's unclear what your issue is (aside from incomplete code). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @JohnColeman could you be more specific about how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It sound like you need to create an **instance** of your class using the `new` keyword.

For example, this would create an instance of the `Student` class:

```
String[] anisaClasses = {"Computer Science", "Math"};
Student anisa = new Student("Anisa", 11, anisaClasses);
```

Now that you have an instance of `Student` in the `anisa` variable, from here you could call the functions on that variable:

```
println("Anisa is in grade " + anisa.getGrade());
```

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-classes) is a tutorial on creating classes in Processing.

Comment: where should I put this new line of code because I tried to put it in String getName() and that didn't work

Comment: @AnisaCallis It really depends on what you want your program to do. But basically you'd need to do it after you create the new instance. Did you read the tutorial I linked?